# RadMenu Performance Issues

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radmenu

I have a page that has a RadMenu and a RadGrid used together. The RadGrid is used in client-side mode. This means that the loading, saving, editing and creation of new records is done via ajax. The grid seems to work fine but after sometime it appears that The menu dropdowns tend to be slower and after more use the entire page freezes. I am not sure whether it is this combo that causes this effect or either of the controls since a lot of js is being used to automate the menu dropdown and the ajax calls to the. This is the order in which the error is reproduced.

The menu control is located up above in a separate iframe and the grid is below in a separate iframe. This makes the scenario more peculiar since different js files are loaded in two iframes and there is no interaction between the two.

What could be the cause of the sudden freezing, a memory leak perhaps? Better still could it be a general problem when a lot of ajax interactions occur and other events are fired before the callbacks return?

On the video once can see that when the grid page loads everything seems fine, but after firing some events and performing some actions, the menu starts taking a lot of time to load. It reaches a point that it takes such a long time for the drop downs to display and eventually the entire browser tab freezes.

I have uploaded a video of the effects and here is the link:
http://megaswf.com/simple_serve/87153/

Comment: I suggest you prepare a sample project and open a support ticket at www.telerik.com. It is very hard to tell what is causing this behavior without reproducing it first.

Answer (score 0):

"Better still could it be a general problem when a lot of ajax interactions occur and other events are fired before the callbacks return?"
- that's most of your problem. Telerik's JavaScript is thrown together, just view source and check out how many scripts are on the page, as well as the inlineJS. Contacting Telerik couldn't hurt, but I doubt it'll help. If you have a float based layout, when you go into edit Telerik, the tools don't work because they're relying on absolute positioning. I had to find my own solution. Good luck.